# Wiring uWSGI to work with Django and nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, uwsgi, wsgi

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup [`uWSGI`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with [`Django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [`nginx`](https://www.nginx.com/) on [`Ubuntu`**`16.04`**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes).

It all works fine up until the very last step (oh the irony...) where I try to execute this command:

```
sudo service uwsgi start
```

If fails with the following error:

> Failed to start uwsgi.service: Unit uwsgi.service not found.

Others seem to get a similar error:

> Failed to start uwsgi.service: Unit uwsgi.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

The issue appears to be related to the version of Ubuntu. While that tutorial is aimed at Ubuntu 14.04, it seems it will not work for newer versions because [in version 15 Ubuntu switched from the `upstart` init daemon to the `systemd` init daemon](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2895517/ubuntu-just-switched-to-systemd-the-project-sparking-controversy-throughout-linux.html).

**How can I use `systemd` to launch uWSGI so that it works with nginx and Django?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The **first** modification needed is to the **`/etc/uwsgi/sites/firstsite.ini`** file. The only change needed is replacing the permissions from `664` to **`666`**. The script would look like this:

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstsite
base = /home/user

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

**Secondly**, as we're using `systemd` rather than `upstart`, the following file is **not needed** and can be removed: **`/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`**

**Third**, we create the following `systemd` script at **`/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Refresh the state of the systemd init system with this new uWSGI service on board

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

In order to start the script you'll need to run the following:

```
sudo systemctl start uwsgi
```

In order to start `uWSGI` on reboot, you will also need:

```
sudo systemctl enable uwsgi
```

You can use the following to check its status:

```
systemctl status uwsgi
```

Some further details can be found [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html).

Comment: How do you make systemd use a python virtualenv? When I run `systemctl status uwsgi` I get `ImportError: No module named site`.

Comment: epic..... i was struggling for so long with this.... thank you for the straight-forward easy step-by-step solution you have written here. +1

Comment: I used it a few times ,very helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

To get around that error: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` for the newly created *uwsgi.service* file to be loaded.

To make service start on each reboot: `sudo systemctl enable uwsgi`.